# Unable to run Python app outside of PyCharm due to ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module, python-packaging

I am working within a large Python codebase that has multiple sub-packages which contain their own Python apps. Note that these sub-packages are local source code and must be installed via `pip install -e .\subpackage_name`.

Because one of these apps import from the other sub-packages, I run into a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage_name.foo'`. However, after creating a "Run Configuration" in PyCharm and checking the "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" and "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH", the `ModuleNotFoundError` is not reproduced and I can run the app just fine.

I would like some insight into what is happening underneath the hood here. I need to be able to start the Python application from a PowerShell instance. More specifically...

**1.)** What kind of arguments does PyCharm inject into the Command Line to add Content & Source roots?

**2.)** Is there something else that PyCharm does behind the scenes within the "Run Configuration" besides modifying the PYTHONPATH that would allow the Python process to "see" other sub-packages within the same project root?

Edit:

For further clarification, this codebase follows a "[flat layout](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#flat-layout)".
It looks something like this:

```
project-root
    - .venv

    - logs

    - subpackage_one
        - subpackage_one.egg-info
        - __init__.py
        - subpackage_one.py
        - setup.cfg
        - setup.py

    - subpackage_two
        - subpackage_two.egg-info
        - __init__.py
        - subpackage_two.py        
        - setup.cfg    
        - setup.py

    - subpackage_three
        - subpackage_three.egg-info
        - __init__.py
        - subpackage_three.py
        - setup.cfg
        - setup.py

    - tests
        - subpackage_one_tests
        - subpackage_two_tests
        - subpackage_three_tests
    
    - pytest.ini
```

The `setup.py` files of this project look like:

```py
# Contents of all setup.py files

from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

and the `setup.cfg` looks like:

```
# setup.cfg example

[metadata]
name = subpackage_x
author = wisenickel
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10.6

[options]
packages = find:


install_requires =
    scikit-learn == 1.1.2
    scipy == 1.9.0
    sklearn == 0.0
    spacy == 3.4.1
    text2num == 2.4.0
    torch == 1.12.1
    transformers == 4.21.2
    ujson == 1.35
    wordcloud == 1.8.2.2

[options.extras_require]
testing =
    pytest>=7.0
    pytest-cov>=4.0
    mypy>=0.991
```

Subpackages One & Two exist individually and do not import from anything other than the virtual environment. However `subpackage_three` imports from `subpackage_one` and `subpackage_two`, so no circular imports exist. The `ModuleNotFoundError` exception is raised when `subpacakge_one` imports `subpackage_one.foo`

I should note that when PyTest launches the `subpackage_three` python app and the sequence of imports happens as stated above, no `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised. I suspect this is because the `pytest.ini` in the project-root looks like the following

```
[pytest]
addopts = -v

pythonpath =
    .
    subpackage_one
    subpackage_two
    subpackage_three
    tests
    tests/subpackage_one
    tests/subpackage_two
    tests/subpackage_three

testpaths =
    subpackage_one
    subpackage_two
    subpackage_three
    tests
    tests/subpackage_one
    tests/subpackage_two
    tests/subpackage_three
```

Comment: Sounds like the module isn't in PYTHONPATH. Examine PYTHONPATH in both environments, i.e. PowerShell, and while running via PyCharm. PyCharm is changing the value of PYTHONPATH to include the sources of the subpackages and it should be pretty obvious how it's doing it while looking at both env vars side-by-side. You can examine the environment variables within the code using `os.environ`.

Comment: There should be no need to modify `PYTHONPATH` if the dependencies are installed correctly (as editable or not). -- The question should be edited to clarify what the project directory structure looks like and why `PYTHONPATH` modifications are deemed necessary.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I have examined the PYTHONPATH during runtime in both environments, the directory which includes the module that raises the `ModuleNotFoundError` is in the PYTHONPATH. In fact the only difference between the PYTHONPATH in both environments is the addition of PyCharm related paths.

Comment: It might not be the cause of your issue, but... The project directory structure seems problematic to me. Having `setup.py` right next to `__init__.py` in the same directory is a red flag for me.-- Maybe look again what the "flat layout" should look like: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/

Comment: @sinoroc I removed the `setup.py` files from the subpackages and re-installed the packages again with no issue. But I still reproduced the ModuleNotFoundError. In any case can you elaborate why you think having the `setup.py` and `__init__.py` in the same directory is problematic? I haven't seen this said anywhere else.

Comment: You can not have `setup.py` and `__init__.py` in the same directory. That is not how Python packaging works. Look again at all the examples. Look at other Python project. -- As it is now, I can not help you with your question. I recommend you rewrite your question from top to bottom. Focus on the actual issue. Provide a [mre].